# Cross-posting or Move a Question to CrossValidated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm beginning to think my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317210/53848 could be a better fit for CrossValidated. *(I've read this link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5085/53848 so I have guidance on how to cross-post.)*

I'm asking about this specific question, whether to it would be best moved or cross posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I moved it. The question is not a mathematical question.